# What is a bootstrap class and how is itused in frameworks like spring?

Tags: java, spring

What is a **bootstrap class** in Java? And how that is being used in frameworks like Spring?

Answer (score 0):

> What is Bootstrap class in java ?

Bootstrap classes are the classes that comprise the Java platform, including the classes in rt.jar and several other important jar files. These classes get into action whenever you launch a JVM.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html

> And how that is being used in Frameworks like Spring?

All java frameworks/code are dependent on JVM to execute and transitively on bootstrap classes.